# MongoDB Bson unique mapper serializer

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, bson

im working with mongodb3.6 and .NetCore2.0, following the **[mongo-csharp-driver2.5](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/bson/mapping/) documentation**.

i want to add a Bson unique map serializer for some fields. like in here:

```
public class UserAccount : Person
{
    [Required]
    [**i want this to be unique also, like i set it required**] 
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string UserCode { get; set; }
}
```

i searched for it in documentation, also google it, but didn't find any help in C# (regarding the mapping clause).

Answer (score 1):

Custom serializer, which checks whether `Required` property is filled or not, could do its job on client side by examining the model. However checking whether the value of document property is unique requires request to the database which will search for the documents with such property value. It will kill performance of model serialization, especially if requested field is not indexed in MongoDB.

That's why I believe you should not check property uniqueness during model serialization. It should be checked on MongoDB server side during document insert attempt. MongoDB provides such capability out of the box with [Unique Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/). The only thing you should do is to create an unique index on the corresponding property:

```
db.userAccounts.createIndex( { "UserName": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Now if you try to insert document with duplicated property value, you'll get the following exception:

[image]

Comment: You could also make the Username field the BsonId in the collection.

Comment: Correct, IDs are unique by definition. But probably OP also needs uniqueness for non-id properties.

Comment: i already have an id, so i need other fields to be unique,  and was thinking in a way to achieve it by annotation

Comment: So, as I've shown in my answer, it's a bad idea. Unique index is the proper way to achieve this.